# Using `system` with a long string VS multiple arguments

Tags: ruby, neovim

I run the following shell command:

```
nvim +CheckHealth +'w ~/Desktop/file.txt' +qall
```

This calls `nvim` ([Neovim](https://neovim.io/)) and tells it to run three commands in succession:

1. `CheckHealth` to verify common errors. It runs in a buffer.
2. `w ~/Desktop/file.txt` to save that same buffer to a file.
3. `qall` to close all buffers.

I’m trying to run this from ruby, using `system`. If I run it as a single argument, it works fine:

```
system("nvim +CheckHealth +'w ~/Desktop/file.txt' +qall")
```

However, it fails (it runs but does not output a file) if ran as multiple arguments:

```
system("nvim", "+CheckHealth", "+'w ~/Desktop/file.txt'", "+qall")
```

What am I doing wrong? Note **I am not asking for workarounds**. I have a workaround, which is to run it as a single argument. My question is **why doesn’t it work when ran as multiple arguments**? What am I misunderstanding about `system`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the single argument version of `system`:

```
system("nvim +CheckHealth +'w ~/Desktop/file.txt' +qall")
```

You're launching a shell and handing it that whole string:

```
nvim +CheckHealth +'w ~/Desktop/file.txt' +qall
```

to execute. That means that everything in that string will be interpreted by the shell; in particular, the shell will be handling the single quotes in `+'w ~/Desktop/file.txt'` and by the time vim gets to parse its argument list, it sees three arguments that look like this:

1. `+CheckHealth`
2. `+w ~/Desktop/file.txt`
3. `+qall`

In the multi-argument version of `system`:

```
system("nvim", "+CheckHealth", "+'w ~/Desktop/file.txt'", "+qall")
```

no shell will be launched (a good thing as you don't have to worry about shell command injection and escaping) so the single quotes in the `+w` argument won't be removed by the shell. That means that vim sees these arguments:

1. `+CheckHealth`
2. `+'w ~/Desktop/file.txt'`
3. `+qall`

Presumably vim isn't happy with the single quotes in the second argument.

Executive summary:

- The single argument version of `system` uses a shell to parse the command line, the multi-argument version doesn't use a shell at all.
- The single quotes in `+'w ~/Desktop/file.txt'` are there to keep the shell from treating that as two arguments, they're not there for vim.
- If you're using the multi-argument version of `system` (which you should be doing), then you'd say:

  ```
  system("nvim", "+CheckHealth", "+w ~/Desktop/file.txt", "+qall")
  ```

  and not have to worry about quoting and escaping things to get past the shell.

Comment: “The single quotes in `+'w ~/Desktop/file.txt'` are there to keep the shell from treating that as two arguments, they're not there for vim.” Precisely what I was missing. Thank you.